# Returning error early from a function that returns an observable

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a function and a validation helper function that reads in a tsv file as a string. I'm trying to practice my reactive programming by even doing synchronous tasks using rxjs. I know this might not be the perfect use case for it, but I know it should be possible.

Here's it in pseudocode in it's simplest form:

```js
public readTsv(tsv: string): Observable<TsvAsObject> {
  if (!tsv || tsv.length < 1) {
    return Observable.throw('null or empty tsv file passed');
  }
  // check tsv headers
  this.validHeadersObs(tsv.split('\n')[0]) // pass the first line of the tsv string
    .filter(valid => valid === false)
    .subscribe(() => {
      return Observable.throw('invalid tsv headers')
    });

  // omitted logic that processes the tsv and then returns it as an observable

  return Observable.of(tsvAsObject);
}
```

I've tested my validHeaders() function and I know that it works. It returns a stream of booleans checking each column header. As soon as a pair of headers doesn't match, it will return an Observable.of(false):

```js
private validHeadersObs(headerLine: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const headers$ = Observable.from(headerLine.split('\t'));
  const validHeaders = ['columnName1', 'columnName2', 'columnName3'];

  return headers$
    .mergeMap((value, index) => Observable.of(value === validHeaders[index]));
}
```

The problem is that readTsv() does not return `Observable.throw('invalid tsv headers')` because I'm not sure how to return early from the function from within a subscribe. Is there a way to "double return" from inside an arrow function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so looking at what you're trying to do, there's one red flag I see: In a function that is going to return an observable, there probably shouldn't be a `subscribe` call *unless* it's inside the body of another Observable.

What you'll want to do is:

1. Throw the argument validation error as soon as you can. This enables you to handle it synchronously if you choose, it also means that if you're using it in RxJS (for example, in a switchMap) it will still propagate down the error channel of the observable.
2. Chain your `validHeadersObs` call into the next action you'd like to take. This is actually no different than what you'd need to do with a promise (think `validate.then(returnAthing)`, `validate.map(returnAthing)` isn't much different in this case).

The problem in your current code is you're starting that work by
subscribing, it's async so it doesn't return, then you carry on and
return the "happy path" observable. If returning the "happy path"
observable depends on the async feedback from your validation call,
you'll need to chain it.

(Small note, if any of the tsv processing logic happens to be asynchronous, you'll want to use a `switchMap` instead of a `map`)

This should do it:

```ts
public readTsv(tsv: string): Observable<TsvAsObject> {
  if (!tsv || tsv.length < 1) {
    // throw an error as soon as you can
    throw new TypeError('null or empty tsv file passed');
  }

  // check tsv headers
  return this.validHeadersObs(tsv.split('\n')[0]) 
    .map(valid => {
      if (!valid) {
        throw new Error('invalid tsv headers');
      }

      // omitted logic that processes the tsv here

      return tsvAsObject
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755806/how-to-return-from-observable-in-typescript-method-with-return-type) question about angular http services, I solved the problem by creating a custom Observable with `Observable.create()`. I think this is called using a higher order observable? In any case...

```js
public buildMenusFromTsv(tsv: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    Observable.of((tsv && tsv.length > 0) as boolean)
      .filter(valid => valid === false)
      .map(() => Observable.throw('null or empty tsv file passed')
      .subscribe(err => observer.error(err));

    // check tsv headers
    this.validHeadersObs(tsv.split('\n')[0])
      .filter(valid => valid === false)
      .map(() => Observable.throw('invalid tsv headers')
      .subscribe(err => observer.error(err));

    // omitted logic that processes the tsv and then returns it as an observable

    observer.next(Observable.of(tsvAsObject));
    observer.complete();
  });
}
```

Bonus: I found a snazzy operator to compare observable streams instead of the clunky `mergeMap()`

```js
private validHeadersObs(headerLine: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const headers$ = Observable.from(headerLine.split('\t'));
  const validHeaders$ = Observable.from(['columnName1', 'columnName2', 'columnName3']);

  return headers$.sequenceEqual(validHeaders$);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

### keep non-async functions *simple* without Rx logic

If you try to do everything in Rx async streams this will increase the cognitive overload and distract from the real issue you want to solve. So even though you want to practice Rx, don't overdo it.

```js
private allHeadersAreValid(headerLine: string): boolean {
  const validHeadersInOrder = ['columnName1', 'columnName2', 'columnName3'];

  return headerLine.split('\t')
    .map((field, index) => field === validHeaders[index])
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc && curr, true);
}
```

### No `subscribe()` inside functions, only `Observables`

By subscribing inside your function you loose the lazyness of Observables and are already executing code which might never be needed. Because we have now made the validation a sync function you can easily test it and use it to test preconditions before doing actual work.

```js
public readTsv(tsv: string): Observable<TsvAsObject> {
  if (!tsv || tsv.length < 1) {
    return Observable.throw('null or empty tsv file passed');
  }

  if(!allHeadersAreValid(tsv)) {
    return Observable.throw('invalid tsv headers');
  }

  // omitted logic that processes the tsv and then returns it as an observable

  return Observable.of(tsvAsObject);
}
```

Downside from above code example is that you still do work before actual `subscribing` because the `allHeadersAreValid` is already evaluated. To make everything be lazy again you can use [`Defer()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) to defer execution of the code to the actual moment of subscription.

```js
public readTsv(tsv: string): Observable<TsvAsObject> {
  return Observable.defer(() => {
    if (!tsv || tsv.length < 1) {
      return Observable.throw('null or empty tsv file passed');
    }

    if(!allHeadersAreValid(tsv)) {
      return Observable.throw('invalid tsv headers');
    }

    // omitted logic that processes the tsv and then returns it as an observable

    return Observable.of(tsvAsObject);
  });
}
```

Now your validation functions are sync and easily testable but your `readTsv` function is still Observable and lazy as expected.

Comment: For the answer I wrote, is it the same level of "laziness" as your solution with `Observable.defer()`?